# Vaadin 23 user online tracking

Tags: session, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I would like to implement a functionality that will show that the current user is online on a website. To do that I need to track it somehow. For example, I can use `com.vaadin.flow.server.SessionInitListener`, but the problem is that the user session can last for a long time, even if the user is not interacting with the website. Just keeps the browser open. Is there a better approach with Vaadin framework how to implement this?

Comment: So is the user _not_ online if it has the browser open at that page?  If
you only consider activity a measurement for online-ness, then you will
most likely have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Or change to aggressive idle-detection.  Basically telling the user,
that you don't want them if they don't interact.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks - I'll use `SessionInitListener/sessionDestroy` in order to implement this